# Index Listing and Sorting Files and Folders exclude PHP

Tags: php, file, directory

Im very very new here just starting my Programming Job and already need a help! :) Well, I want that my script show first Folders and then files so like Folders have more Priority to be first then last. Here is the script

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
{
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !preg_match('/\.php$/i', $file) && !preg_match('/robots.txt$/i', $file))
    {
        $thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution it looks like this:

[image]

The black squares are just private things.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index of</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<?php 
    $dir = scandir("./");
    $icon = "http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/512/very-basic-file-icon.png";
    foreach ($dir as $key => $elem) {
        switch (pathinfo($elem,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) {
            case 'php':
                $icon = "https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/php-outline.png";
                break;
            case 'html':
                $icon = "https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/html-file-with-code-symbol_318-45756.jpg";
                break;
            case 'css':
                $icon = "https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/css-file-format-symbol_318-45329.jpg";
                break;
            default:
                $icon = 'https://1001freedownloads.s3.amazonaws.com/icon/thumb/335424/Very-Basic-Opened-Folder-icon.png';
                break;
        }

        if($key % 5 == 0) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }

        if(pathinfo($elem,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) != 'php') {
            echo "<td><a href='$elem'><img src='$icon' height='100px' width='100px'/>$elem</a></td>";
        }
    }
?>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah thats what i need, how to can i add a code to excluse php files to be shown?

Comment: if extension is `php` don't `echo`. `if($ext != "php") echo`

Comment: hmm strange doesnt work it still shows the php file in the directory.

Comment: its say error by me and doesnt load I think I do something wrong. its showed php because my server was lame to update the file. can you just post the code? thx

Comment: But HTTP 500 error is a server error thats a different problem.

Comment: it happens all the time when something wrong in code atleast by me but when i remove `?= 'php')` it works but then it shows php of course. EDIT: I use ! insted ? and it works. thank you

Comment: @eXme OMG I dont know why this could happen... Yeah ist a `!` not a question mark I'm officially dumb...

Comment: But I noticed it shows 2 other directories the one where you go the the domain and the last folder or like "../" to go back. is it possible to exclude them by listing? I tryed scandir to change with opendir but it doesnt show anything at all. http://exme.net/php/index.php i dont know this case commands and cant find any tutorials 0o

Comment: Just do it the same way `$ext != '.' || $ext != '..'` where `$ext` is `pathinfo($elem,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`